# Xamarin Forms xam.plugins.pushnotifications issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

HI I am trying to add the "Xam.Plugin.PushNotification" plugin to my xamarin forms application but get this strange error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 26.0.2-rc1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I believe this error is about updating the package version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.V4' etc to latest version.

Comment: Sorry, could't reproduce your issue, what is your XF version and your `Xam.Plugin.PushNotification` version?

Answer (score 0):

Hold your horses friend, this xam.plugin.pushnotification package was recently announced as [DEPRECATED](https://github.com/BDBPayroll/xamarin-plugins/blob/master/PushNotification/README.md).
If you ain't public with PushNotifications yet you should strongly consider migration.